How can I visible/unvisible group items for PrimeNG dropdown?
I want to make visible/unvisible group items if the group has items when I click on group header.
Is it possible?
For example, I want to see 3 items (AA,BB,CC) in dropdown, first 2 options(AA and BB) should be selectable and when I click on third option (CC), sub items (CC1, CC2, CC3) should be visible. How can I do?
<p-dropdown 
  [options]="groupOptions" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" 
  placeholder="Select"
  [group]="true">
      <ng-template let-group pTemplate="group">
          <div class="flex align-items-center">   
               <span >{{ group.label }}</span>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>


groupOptions= [
    { value: '1', label: 'AA' },
    { value: '2', label: 'BB' },
    {
      label: 'CC',
      value: '3',
      items: [
        { value: '31', label: 'CC1' },
        { value: '32', label: 'CC2' },
        { value: '33', label: 'CC3' }
      ]
    }
  ];


We can use a combination of html, css and logic to achieve this, below are the styles used, we can use a custom class custom-grouped-dropdown and scope them to this dropdown alone, then use ::ng-deep so that its visible to all contents of the component
::ng-deep .custom-grouped-dropdown {
  p-dropdownitem {
    padding: 0px !important;
    display: block;
  }
  .p-dropdown-item {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}

Then we can maintain a property called hidden on each item of the group and use it to toggle the data visibility using *ngIf, I also added a button to toggle the functionality
<br /><br /><br />
<p-dropdown
  class="custom-grouped-dropdown"
  [options]="groupOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup"
  placeholder="Select"
  [group]="true"
>
  <ng-template let-group pTemplate="group">
    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <span>{{ group.label }}</span>
      <button (click)="toggle(group)">{{!group.hidden ? '+' : '-'}}</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <div
      class="flex align-items-center"
      *ngIf="item.hidden"
      style="padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem !important"
    >
      <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>

Finally I created a function that will update all the children hidden flag based on the toggle action.
Note: Primeng looks like it only supports one level of grouping so I did not bother with recursion
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic-demo.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown-basic-demo.scss'],
})
export class DropdownBasicDemo {
  selectedGroup = null;
  groupOptions = [
    {
      value: '1',
      label: 'AA',
      items: [
        { value: '31', label: 'CC1' },
        { value: '32', label: 'CC2' },
        { value: '33', label: 'CC3' },
      ],
    },
    {
      value: '2',
      label: 'BB',
      items: [
        { value: '31', label: 'CC1' },
        { value: '32', label: 'CC2' },
        { value: '33', label: 'CC3' },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'CC',
      value: '3',
      items: [
        { value: '31', label: 'CC1' },
        { value: '32', label: 'CC2' },
        { value: '33', label: 'CC3' },
      ],
    },
  ];

  toggle(group: any) {
    console.log(group);
    if (group?.items.length) {
      group.items.forEach((item: any) => (item.hidden = !item.hidden));
      group.hidden = !!group.items[0].hidden;
    }
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
